# how do I fix leaking concrete basement floor?

Tags: plumbing

I suspect there is an old cracked metal pipe, under the concrete floor of my basement! Whenever we get heavy or lengthy rain, the floor would slowly leak and rusty water would cover the floor.

Comment: do you have a sump pump? I don't see how the rain-based problem points to a pipe, which would be more of an all the time problem...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.